# Regex Data Studio exclude URL parameters

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I have managed to use a Regex on Google Data Studio to create a 'last path' directory value which works great, using;

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT( Page , '.*/(.*)/' )
```

Is it possible to exclude URLs with parameters?

So for example the regex matches with;

/directory1/

/directory1/?var=1

/directory1/?var=2

So I wish to exclude any ?var= URLs but not limited to the var parameter value.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `REGEXP_EXTRACT( Page , '.*/(.*)/$' )`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's returning null so doesn't work...

Comment: I think you are on the right track but there is no match once a ? is included in the string

Comment: See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/g0mVmK/1) it works. It does not gobble the questions marks.

Comment: You were right thanks, some of the top traffic results were nulled but further down it collected the correct results. Thank you!

Comment: Can we include multiple conditional excludes so for instance, exclude URL parameters, and exclude URLs containing 'error-404' ? Sorry for the big ask.

Comment: If it involves lookaheads, it is not possible here, you use the library that does not support them.

Comment: Does your regex library support lookaheads?

Answer (score 0):

To solve current issue use

```js
REGEXP_EXTRACT( Page , '.*/(.*)/$' )
```

The anchor `$` stops from matching anything with more text after `/`. If there is a query string, no match will occur.

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```